# makecell package and column width

Tags: tables, makecell

To create the tables I use the makecell package. 
I would need the last four columns have a with a smaller width than the first: this is my attempt

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,systeme}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{5pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{| *{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm} | *{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}} |}
\hline
Sostanza & $\theta$ & $\eta$ & $\nu$ & $\rho$ \\ \hline\hline
Acido benzoico & a & a & a & a \\ \hline
Saccarosio & b & b & b & b \\ \hline
Acido salicilico & c & c & c & c \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

and the error message:

*! Paragraph ended before @@array was complete.*

Could you help me?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem has nothing to do with `makecell` package. In your column definitions is missing one `}`. However, instead of

```
\begin{tabular}{| *{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm} | % here is mised }
                  *{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}|} }
```

is simpler to write

```
\begin{tabular}{| >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}|
             *{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}  |} }
```

complete MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,systeme}  % "amssymb" load "amsfonts"
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{5pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
\centering
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{| >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}|
             *{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}  |} }
    \hline
Sostanza            & $\theta$  & $\eta$    & $\nu$ & $\rho$    \\ \hline\hline

Acido benzoico      & a         & a         & a     & a         \\ \hline
Saccarosio          & b         & b         & b     & b         \\ \hline
Acido salicilico    & c         & c         & c     & c         \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very well. And the column separator between the last columns?

Comment: @user3204810, corrected.